# How can I extract the part of a line included between ":"?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am having trouble parsing this particular line using sed:

```
/media/file/1.bmp app:Stuff I want:
```

Basically I want to get the stuff in between the two colons (`::`), i.e. `Stuff I want` in this case.

I tried

```
sed -r 's/.*app:([\s\w\d]*):.*/\1/'
```

This didnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following  (update: appears \: isn't necessary, : is fine)

```
sed -r 's/.*\:([^\:]*)\:.*/\1/'
```

or per @brandizzi and @joemooney's answer:

```
sed -r 's/.*:([^:]*):.*/\1'
```

or with cut

```
cut -f 2 -d":"
```

Comment: Right. sed is not perl and does not have all the character class shorthands like \w and \d

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to escape the colons... At least @joemooney's  solution worked for me without escaping them.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `sed` for that, awk looks nicer:

```
awk -F : '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "/media/file/1.bmp app:Stuff I want:" | sed -r 's/.*app:([^:]*):.*/\1/'
Stuff I want
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '/media/file/1.bmp app:Stuff I want:' | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

Simple and elegant. Cut is the tool I use for deliminating fields. `-d` notes the deliminating character, `-f 2` tells you to get field 2.